# Reset Observable.interval time on event

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm starting this observable as soon as I get an event

```
Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe()
```

Now, when another event comes in I want to reset the interval to 0. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the environment where you are running this interval.

For one, you can use a [`SerialDisposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/SerialDisposable.html) and keep replacing the contents (and thus disposing the old) when a new event comes in:

```java
final SerialDisposable interval = new SerialDisposable();

public void onEvent() {
    interval.set(
        Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                  .subscribe(/* ... */)
    );
}
```

Alternatively, if you have an event source `Observable`, you can just apply [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#switchMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

```java
PublishSubject<Event> eventSource = PublishSubject.create();

eventSource.switchMap(event -> 
    Observable.Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
)
.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: running in Android env